# Dynamically allocated

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need help, to change the size and arr, in the main function to allocate memory dynamically (dynamically allocated)

this program uses looping for integer numbers for the 1st program, while classes and structs are the second program

program_1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

void display_desc(const int arr[], int size)
{
    int copy_arr[size];
    copy(arr, arr + size, copy_arr);
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (copy_arr[i] > copy_arr[j]) {
                temp = copy_arr[i];
                copy_arr[i] = copy_arr[j];
                copy_arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << copy_arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int size = 5;
    int arr[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    display_desc(arr, size);
}
```

and 
program_2
Change the variable that is in int main () to use dynamic memory allocation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
const int SLOT_ROOM = 5;
class Person {
public:
    Person()
    {
        name = "";
    }
    Person(string names)
    {
        name = names;
    }
    void set_name(string names) { name = names; }
    string get_name() { return name; }
private:
    string name;
};

struct Slot {
    bool blank;
    Person person;
};
class rental {
public:
    Slot used[SLOT_ROOM];
    rental()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SLOT_ROOM; i++) {
            Person person;
            used[i].person = person;
            used[i].blank = true;
        }
    }
    int in(const Person person)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SLOT_ROOM; i++) {
            if (used[i].blank) {
                used[i].blank = false;
                used[i].person = person;
                cout << "used in position " << i << endl;
                return i;
            }
        }
        cout << "the rental is full" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    bool out(int i)
    {
        used[i].blank = true;
    }

    Slot* get_rental_list()
    {
        return used;
    }

    void print_person_list()
    {
        cout << endl
             << "List rental" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < SLOT_ROOM; i++) {
            cout << "Slot rental to " << i << endl;
            cout << "Name: " << used[i].person.get_name() << endl;
            cout << "Avail: " << used[i].blank << endl
                 << endl;
        }
    }

private:
    int SLOT_ROOM = 2;
    string time_rental;
};
int main()
{

    rental rental;

    Person person_1("make");
    Person person_2("angel");
    rental.in(person_1);
    rental.in(person_2);
    rental.print_person_list();
    rental.out(2);
    rental.print_person_list();
    rental.in(person_2);
    rental.print_person_list();
}
```

please help, I don't understand about using dynamic memory allocation

I still learn c ++

Comment: Your code is technically invalid since C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), it's an extension that *some* compilers might have added in a non-portable way. Use `std::vector` instead. Using `std::vector` is also the standard solution to any kind of "dynamic array".

Comment: I maybe wrong but last I checked, dynamic memory allocation in C++  needs `new` to be used.

Comment: Also, you know about [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), so I think it should be easy for you to find and use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) as well.

Comment: @JoeyMallone That's not been true since the STL days :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, ah yes, there was that caveat in my statement. I just wanted to say that the OP is confusing *"dynamic memory allocation"*, which requires `new` (even if that `new` happens inside an STL container), with Variable Length Arrays (VLAs). At least, that's what I felt/understood from the OP's code.

Comment: @JoeyMallone Okay cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
int arr[size];
```

to

```
int* arr = new int[size];
```

You need to make the same change to `int copy_arr[size];` in `display_desc`.

You also need to `delete[]` memory once you've finished with it.

```
delete[] arr;
```

at the end of main, and `delete[] copy_arr;` at the end of `display_desc`.

In the second question it's harder to understand what you want. Why do you want to use dynamic allocation? Your code looks perfectly good as it is. You also don't say which variable it is that you want to use dynamic allocation.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to recommend using `std::vector` instead?

Comment: It undoubtedly would be better to use std::vector, but I have a feeling the advice wouldn't be followed. Seems likely the OP has been told to replace his VLA with dynamic allocation by his teacher.

Comment: thanks for the help of the answer program 1, for program 2, which I want to make a dynamic allocation of "string name" variables in class person

Comment: @Meks That sounds like a really bad idea, what do you think you'd gain by doing that?